# Discord.js returning message.delete() is not a function

Tags: discord.js

I am trying to delete the last message sent by my bot (just to keep then channels clean) but when I define lM as channel.send("Test") lM.delete() returns lM.delete() is not a function.
Here is my code:

```js
async function sendMsg(content){
    return await message.channel.send(content)
}
LM = sendMsg("Test")
LM.delete()
```

and this is my error:

```html
LM.delete()
     ^

TypeError: LM.delete is not a function
    at C:\Users\willi\Documents\Discord-bot\main.js:167:30

Node.js v17.4.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the problem, the function was returning a promise, so I just had to do `LM.Message.delete()`.

Comment: OR message.channel.send('message').then(msg => msg.delete())

Comment: @MalikLahlou Yes, that does work but that deletes it immediately, the intention was to delete it later, sorry about the late reply.